# accessing dynamicly generated array names using square brakets in an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, variables

object, contains 'array1'.

```
$Obj -> array1 [12]; // works fine.
```

however, dynamically generating that array name - you can't use square brackets...

```
$var = 'array1';

$Obj -> $var [ 12] ; // nothing. no error, but no result.
```

I had to do

```
$ar = $Obj -> $var ; // copy out array
$ar [12] ; // get value in array.
```

note:

```
$Obj -> $$var [ 12]; // fatal error, cannot access empty property
$Obj -> ($var) [12] ; // error, unexpected '[' or '('
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: `$Obj->{$var}[12]`

Comment: Wonderful! so, the curly brackets mean "evaluate" ? and this can be used in other contexts also i assume. Thanks!